# Set y position of svg using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set `y` value for `tspan` inside svg.

The svg is like this (for simplicity I deleted some part, the full code is here: https://0bin.net/paste/VKLkhpMK#HkAkhB0vVSN-ZVE9yUnWRkbgfzuN+S+bWt+U15wMJxe ):

```
<div class="chart" style="margin-top: -50px">
   <div id="jvwbtduzlfxnprgyeskhiqaoc" style="min-height: 288.7px;">
      <div id="apexchartsq5s3epfr" class="apexcharts-canvas apexchartsq5s3epfr apexcharts-theme-light" style="width: 270px; height: 288.7px;">
         <svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="270" height="288.70000000000005" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev" class="apexcharts-svg" xmlns:data="ApexChartsNS" transform="translate(0, 0)" style="background: transparent;">
            <g id="SvgjsG1016" class="apexcharts-datalabels-group" transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1)" style="opacity: 1;">
              <text id="SvgjsText1017" font-family="&quot;Nunito&quot;" x="138" y="138" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="auto" font-size="16px" font-weight="600" fill="#008744" class="apexcharts-text apexcharts-datalabel-label" style="font-family: Nunito;">

                   <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1018">8 / 8 + 1</tspan> // set y="150" (the value for id is unique, so I can't using it)

               </text>
               <text id="SvgjsText1019" font-family="&quot;Nunito&quot;" x="138" y="170" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="auto" font-size="14px" font-weight="400" fill="#373d3f" class="apexcharts-text apexcharts-datalabel-value" style="font-family: Nunito;">100%</text>
             </g>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried like this:

```
<script>
   $('.apexcharts-datalabel-label tspan').attr('y', 150);
</script>
```

But nothing changed, I don't know why. My code above working on other page, but not working for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selector should work:

`.apexcharts-text.apexcharts-datalabel-label tspan`

So the query would change to:

`$('.apexcharts-text.apexcharts-datalabel-label tspan').attr('y', 150);`